# Get related model through javascript in yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2

I'm getting a Row from a table through javascript and action in `Productnames` controller.

The fields I'm getting is *productid*, *productname* and *bottletype*. So far it's fine.

**JS**

```
<?php
$script = <<< JS
$('#catid').change(function(){   
    var catid = $(this).val();

     $.get('index.php?r=production/productnames/get-for-production',{ catid : catid }, function(data){
        alert(data.unitprice);
        // var data = $.parseJSON(data);
        // $('#productnames-bottletype').attr('value',data.bottletype)

    });
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

**Action** in `ProductnamesController`

```
public function actionGetForProduction($catid)
    {
        $bottle = Productnames::findOne(['productnames_productname'=>$catid]);
        //$bottle -> select(['productnames.productnames_productname','productnames.bottletype','bottlename.unitprice'])->from('Productnames')->leftJoin('bottlename','productnames.bottletype = bottlename.bottlename')->where(['productnames_productname'=>$catid])->limit(1);
        echo Json::encode($bottle);
    }
```

Now I want to get data from *bottlename* table which is related to *Productname* table as `productname.bottletype = bottlename.bottlename`.

Table `bottlename` has 3 fields:

> id, bottlename, unitprice.

I'm getting *productname*, *bottlename* from above mentioned code. W**hat I want is to get the *unitprice* along with the above data.**

Below is a screenshot what I'm getting now:

[image: Here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have in Productnames model a 'bottlename' relation to 'bottlename' table (I call it bottlenameRelation to distinguish from bottlename field):

```
public function getBottlenameRelation() { 
       return $this->hasOne(Bottlename::className(), ['bottlename' => 'bottletype']); 
}
```

Then in the action add bottlenameRelation reference:

```
public function actionGetForProduction($catid)
{
        $bottle = Productnames::find()->with('bottlenameRelation')->where(['productnames_productname'=>$catid])->asArray()->one();
        echo Json::encode($bottle);
}
```

The json in output will contain bottlename relation fields.

For sake of completeness, you could output json in this way, that also add correct HTTP header:

```
public function actionGetForProduction($catid)
{
     \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        $bottle = Productnames::find()->with('bottlenameRelation')->where(['productnames_productname'=>$catid])->asArray()->one();
     return $bottle;
}
```

Comment: It is not showing the "unitprice" field in the output. The output is as it was earlier